# How do I get Joystick Axis to be recognized on a Unity WebGL Build

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, joystick, unity-webgl, gamepad

I am currently trying to set up a controller with my WebGL Unity Game to make an object move left and right. The controller is an iNNEXT SNES USB controller. I have mapped the Horizontal D-Pad controls to:

```
Type: Joystick Axis 
Axis: 4th axis (Joysticks) 
Joy Num: Get Motion from all Joysticks
```

[image]
The controls work in the Unity Editor. When using the D-Pad, the player moves left and right. However, once I build the game for WebGL the Joystick controls are no longer recognized and the object no longer moves left or right. I also tried adding print statement for "Input.GetAxis("Horizontal")" and I receive -1 or 1 while testing in Unity, but when I build the game for WebGL, it stays on 0.

```
void Update () {

    if (Input.GetAxis("HorizontalDPAD") > 0){
        MoveRight();
    }else if(Input.GetAxis("HorizontalDPAD") < 0){
        MoveLeft();
    }
}

public void MoveLeft(){
   transform.position += Vector3.left * movementSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
}

public void MoveRight(){
   transform.position += Vector3.right * movementSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
}
```

I am not receiving any error messages, and Input.GetAxis("HorizontalDPAD") works in the Unity Editor. It just appears that the Joystick controls are not being recognized in WebGL. Please let me know if you have a solution, or any ideas to test.

Comment: Have you read [Input in WebGL](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/webgl-input.html)?

Comment: @shingo Thank you for your response! I have read that, however, it does not seem to explain this issue. If it does, could you provide more information as to what I am missing?

Comment: So what's the result of GetJoystickNames?

Comment: @shingo I added - print(Input.GetJoystickNames()[0]); - in the Update() method - When I run the game as a WebGL build, it prints "USB Gamepad  (Vendor: ### Product: ####)" - It is still the same situation, where the D-Pad works in the Unity Editor, but not in the WebGL build. All of the other buttons work in the Unity Editor, and the WebGL build - any ideas? or is there something I need to do with the result of GetJoystickNames?

Comment: It sounds like your gamepad isn't supported in Chrome yet. If it was, the ID string would have "STANDARD GAMEPAD" in it. Can you share the vendor and product IDs for your gamepad?

Comment: Yes definitely - Vendor: 0079 Product: 0011 - Where are are you checking if the remotes are supported? If these controllers aren't supported yet, I'd like to find some that are

Comment: @shingo I found that the Vertical Joysticks work in this Unity WebGL Demo - https://forum.unity.com/threads/simple-input-use-custom-input-providers-like-joysticks-ui-buttons-and-d-pads-open-source.520504/  so the controllers must be supported - there is just something I must be missing.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing cross-platform input in `edit -> project settings -> script execution order`

[image]